# Hover on areas not on point in Highchart-polygon

Tags: highcharts, hover, polygon

I have one chart and i want to include hover on area but i found it works only on point only.

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Target',
            type: 'polygon',
            data: [[153, 42], [149, 46], [149, 55], [152, 60]], 
            color: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get(),
            enableMouseTracking: true

        }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/onhfLqdm/3/

As area is bounded by points so how can i hover area instead of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**  On hover on each polygon asker wants to show data coming from json.To do so in a div out of container please view [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/onhfLqdm/16/)

**In Tooltip** One more option to show some info coming from json ,tooltip can be used.Put your data using some name like "someText" (as in my fiddle )and get it in formatter function of tooltip using

```
  this.options.someText
```

[See this fiddle for data in tooltiip](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/onhfLqdm/17/)

**Old Answer:**

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {

            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                     $("#polygon").html('Moused over Event')
                        .css('color', 'green');
                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                    $("#polygon").html('Moused out Event')
                        .css('color', 'red');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Fiddle link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/onhfLqdm/6/)

Comment: I guess that tooltip should be printed inside area and display "current" value inside, instaead of referring to the closest point.

Comment: you are right ,@SebastianBochan , I realized that later. He wants all different polygon specific data when hover on polygon.The answer here specific to chart area.